# Parsing & contracting Russian full names

Tags: ios, regex, swift

I have several text fields used to enter full name and short name, among other data. My task is:

1. Check if entered full name matches the standard Russian Cyrillic full name pattern:

`Иванов Иван Иванович` (three capitalized Cyrillic strings separated by spaces)

2. If it matches, create another string by auto-contracting full name according to pattern below and enter it to the corresponding text field:

`Иванов И.И.` (first string, space, first character of the second string, dot, first character of the third string, dot)

3. If it doesn't match, do nothing.

Currently I use the following code:

```
let fullNameArray = fullNameField.text!.characters.split{$0 == " "}.map(String.init)

if fullNameArray.count == 3 {

  if fullNameArray[0] == fullNameArray[0].capitalizedString && fullNameArray[1] == fullNameArray[1].capitalizedString && fullNameArray[2] == fullNameArray[2].capitalizedString {

      shortNameField.text = "\(fullNameArray[0]) \(fullNameArray[1].characters.first!).\(fullNameArray[2].characters.first!)."
   }
}
```

How can I improve it? Maybe regular expressions could help me? If so, could you post some sample code?

Comment: I like to solve my problems with regex generally, but unicode here is annoying. I wouldn't advice to use regex for unicode problems, if an easy solution already exists, like in this example. I understand that you want to shorten your code with regex but, short wouldn't mean simple, actually it would turn your code into a very complex one.

Comment: @Saibot I understand your point. But this code has several problems. One example: I use the same text field for personal names and for organization names. So if user enters a personal name, it should strictly follow our naming customs to be interpreted correctly. `Петров Пётр Петрович` is a correct personal name. `Управление ФПС Москвы` is an organization name, and so on. But this code sometimes interprets both variants in the same way. I'm writing for myself only, so I just wonder if there's more efficient way to do that.

Comment: You can't distinguish personal names and organizational names with regex. However, there is a tool for this: Named Entity Recognizer. This is a Natural Language Processing tool, and I don't know if there is an implementation for Russian NER. Maybe you may want to read this paper: http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=2468252
Do I recommend? No, if you are not willing to study NLP for 20 hours, just be able to to use this tool(if it exists) :)
How do I know this? Actually I'm working on a NLP research project right now.

Comment: @Saibot Well, as I said, I'm writing for myself only. I don't want to distinguish names with regex, it's my problem, not my program's :-) I want to check if I entered valid Russian personal name, and if so, I want my program to automatically shorten it. If it isn't a valid personal name, then I don't want to shorten it. Nothing more, nothing less. I've posted my current solution btw.

Answer (score 1):

My current solution:

```
do {
   let regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: "^\\p{Lu}\\p{Ll}+\\s\\p{Lu}\\p{Ll}+\\s\\p{Lu}\\p{Ll}+$", options: .AnchorsMatchLines)

   if regex.firstMatchInString(fullNameField.text!, options: [], range: NSMakeRange(0, fullNameField.text!.characters.count)) != nil {

      let fullNameArray = fullNameField.text!.characters.split(" ").map(String.init)

      shortNameField.text = "\(fullNameArray[0]) \(fullNameArray[1].characters.first!).\(fullNameArray[2].characters.first!)."
   }
   else {
      shortNameField.text = ""
   }
} catch let error as NSError {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
}
```

Processes my full name pattern correctly.